Can I Hold Two Study Visas from Italy and Switzerland but Reside in One?
I have been awarded full scholarships in both Italy and Switzerland. I applied for a Swiss visa 3 months ago but have not received a response, so I would like to apply for an Italian visa now. My primary choice is to study in Switzerland. Is it possible to have both visas in my passport in case the Swiss visa is approved later?
